# HBase acl commands are too slow

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have configured HBase-1.1.5 and Hadoop-2.7.2 with Kerberos security.

I have enabled authorization for HBase.

When executing any authorization command like `user_permission`, `grant`, `revoke`, etc.

Its getting more than 40 seconds to execute

Below are hbase-site.xml configuration properties

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>IP:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://IP:9000/HBase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>IP1:2181,IP2:2181,IP3:2181</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.port</name>
    <value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
    <value>60010</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
    <value>60020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
    <value>60030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>KERBEROS</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.keytab.file</name>
    <value>masterkeytab</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.keytab.file</name>
    <value>regionserverkeytab</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>masterprincipal</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>regionserverprincipal</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.engine</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.ssl.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.superuser</name>
    <value>@HadoopUser</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
```

Help me to improve performance on HBase acl

Thanks in advance